# Can't deserialize byte[] using Gson

Tags: c#, java, json, json.net, gson

I've got a class written in Java and the same class written in C#. I'm serializing the C# class into a json string and I am trying to deserialize it on the Java side. 
It all went perfectly fine until I've added a byte[] field to both classes.
here are the classes definitions:
C#:

```
public class RegisterRequest : GenericRequest
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string sex { set; get; }
    public string birthday { set; get; }
    public string from { set; get; }
    public string about { set; get; }
    public byte[] image { set; get; }
}
```

Java:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends GenericRequest{
    private String name;
    private String sex;
    private String birthday;
    private String from;
    private String about;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private byte[] image;
}
```

The serialization on the C# side uses: `request.ToJson()` (Json.NET)
and the Java deserialization uses: `RegisterRequest rr = gsonObject.fromJson(msg, RegisterRequest.class);` (using Gson. the msg is the json string)

When I don't send anything in the byte array it still works. But when I do fill the array I get an exception on the Java side: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 159089`

I'm guessing that there needs to be something that marks the begining of an array which Gson identifies but Json.NET doesn't adds to the string?

Comment: @MAXE The deserialization is being done by Gson

Comment: Json is a standard like XML and Gson looks like a library that google wrote

Comment: Apologies, rollback gone wrong >.>

Comment: have you tried using Byte with a capital B in java?

Comment: How does the JSON looks like in UTF-8? Can provide a sample?

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to try serializing a byte[] using gson and see how the output is different from the JSON.Net version. If I remember right, gson expects a bunch of header information in byte arrays. You may have to write a custom deserializer which works with the JSON.Net byte[] data

Comment: @alFReDNSH the Json received looks like:
{"name":"q q","sex":"","birthday":"","from":"","about":"","image":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/+EQskV4aWYAAE1NACoAAAAIAAKHaQAEAAAAAQAACDLqHAAHAAAIDAAAACYAAAAAHOoAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.... (keeping like that for a while more)

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I agree with this one. You cannot send byte arrays without writing a custom deserializer. You could have a whole bunch of issues. Personally I would send the images seperately without using a Json wrapper. My guess is that the parser gets the the Byte[] part, expects a string and then reads binary characters that are outside of the UTF-8 set, which throws the illegal character exception.

Comment: Try constructing a string object from the byte array using UTF-8 encoding in C#

Comment: @FaddishWorm in the end i turned the byte array into short array and it worked. So because your answer of constructing a string is the same idea then please put that as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the piece of input from a comment above

```
"image":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB..."
```

and looking at how Gson serializes `byte[]`

```
"a":[96,-76,32,-69,56,81,-39,-44...
```

the answer is obvious: Gson uses a json array while json.net uses a json string. You must change one or the other. Writing a custom serializer for gson is easy (although I've never tried with `byte[]`), the same probably holds for the other tool.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is a cool question - I am going to go ahead and try and answer this because the comments are getting very long.

Firstly, the problem is your parser when you are reading the data. It gets tricked up on the binary payload and encounters an illegal character exception. This is because it is trying to deal with a big ByteArray, but encounters a character or byte it can't deal with (probably because there is a byte in the binary that cannot be converted to UTF-8. Also,  remember that characters are usually 1 byte in C# and 2 bytes in java as well.

There are 2 reasons that I think could be the cause of this.

1. The gson reader is not picking up on the **"byte[]"** type that you are sending, and it is treating your binary as a UTF-8 encoded string.
2. JSON.NET byte arrays, are not interpreted the same way as that of gson - so it wont work without writing a JSON.NET compatible deserializer

I think you need to keep looking at the data, try changing encodings and also, see if you can get a gson parser for java that gives you more control then this one does :)

Comment: is there an encoding which is more "universal" and has the most chances to be recognized by both sides?

Comment: UTF-16 allows for more characters I think. Have you tried that?

Comment: although UTF-8 and UTF-16 are both variable length encodings I am pretty sure

Comment: Did you try changing it from byte to Byte in java?

Comment: Have you tried making the image field synthetic, or transient to help you debug? Mabe you should make the byte[] synthetic, and then deserialize it manually?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15795/discussion-between-faddishworm-and-yonatan-nir)